# Unable to open Elasticsearch-head plugin – v2.1.1

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to open the elasticsearch-head plugin with this URL http://vmname:9200/_plugin/head, but no luck, i am getting ‘This web page is not available’.

Need your help to fix this, not sure whether I am missing something here.

Please find the details of the environment below,

```
Elasticsearch version: 2.1.1
Plugins: elasticsearch-head
JAVA: java version "1.7.0_05"
OS: Linux 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
```

Plugin installation Logs:

```
[esearch@vmname bin]$ ./plugin install mobz/elasticsearch-head url http://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip
-> Installing mobz/elasticsearch-head...
Trying https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip ...
Downloading ..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................DONE
Verifying https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip checksums if available ...
NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find .sha1 or .md5 file to verify)
Installed head into /opt/elasticsearch-2.1.1/plugins/head
```

ElasticSearch logs:

```
[esearch@vmname bin]$ ./elasticsearch
[2015-12-26 12:51:19,953][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: prctl(PR_GET_NO_NEW_PRIVS): Invalid argument
[2015-12-26 12:51:20,536][INFO ][node                     ] [Gatecrasher] version[2.1.1], pid[19215], build[40e2c53/2015-12-15T13:05:55Z]
[2015-12-26 12:51:20,536][INFO ][node                     ] [Gatecrasher] initializing ...
[2015-12-26 12:51:20,825][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Gatecrasher] loaded [], sites [head]
[2015-12-26 12:51:20,869][INFO ][env                      ] [Gatecrasher] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda3)]], net usable_space [4.8gb], net total_space [27.3gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext3]
[2015-12-26 12:51:24,514][INFO ][node                     ] [Gatecrasher] initialized
[2015-12-26 12:51:24,514][INFO ][node                     ] [Gatecrasher] starting ...
[2015-12-26 12:51:24,646][INFO ][transport                ] [Gatecrasher] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2015-12-26 12:51:24,669][INFO ][discovery                ] [Gatecrasher] elasticsearch/NhlBGx_kTiq7JeeEPihz2w
[2015-12-26 12:51:27,728][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Gatecrasher] new_master {Gatecrasher}{NhlBGx_kTiq7JeeEPihz2w}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2015-12-26 12:51:27,751][INFO ][http                     ] [Gatecrasher] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {[::1]:9200}
[2015-12-26 12:51:27,751][INFO ][node                     ] [Gatecrasher] started
[2015-12-26 12:51:27,850][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Gatecrasher] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

I am able to access the head plugin in Windows 7 without any issue, but I can't able to access the same in Linux.

**EDITED...................................**

Port 9200 is not reachable from outside,

```
[root@ newvm ~]# nc -vz vmname 9200
nc: connect to vmname port 9200 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Whereas the port is LISTENING with in the VM,

```
[root@vmname ~]# nc -vz vmname 9200
Connection to vmname 9200 port [tcp/wap-wsp] succeeded!

[root@ vmname ~]# netstat -nat | grep :9200
tcp        0      0 ::1:9200                    :::*                        LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:9200       :::*                        LISTEN
```

I have disabled the firewall and tried, but the issue still exits!

```
[root@ vmname ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Silly note, but I'm assuming vmname is reachable - you can test using "ping vmname"

Comment: yes, 'vmname' is reachable.

Comment: Do the logs display anything after trying to access http://vmname:9200/_plugin/head?

Comment: @Archit: there are no logs, when I try to access the plugin.

Comment: Can you access just http://vmname:9200?

Comment: @ArchitSaxena: i have edited my findings above, Could not open connection to the host, on port 9200. please share your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have elasticsearch configured to only listen on localhost

You might want to try adding to your elasticsearch.yml the following

network.host: *[networkInterface]*

NOTE: This WILL make your cluster listen on public interfaces, so you'l want to bring that firewall back up and restrict access.

Comment: Thanks! I missed this configuration when I moved to 2.1.1. Previously I used to work with v1.7.1 without this configuration.
I came to know that the default in Elasticsearch 2.x is to bind to localhost only.

Answer (score 0):

make sure plugins directory has sufficient permission for elasticsearch to server the plugin files:

```
sudo chown -R elasticsearch. /usr/share/elasticsearch
```

Comment: I am currently making use of user name ‘esearch’, this user is the owner of the folder /opt/elasticsearch-2.1.1/ and all the subfolders under it. 
Is there any other specific permission I need provide?

Comment: no, but make sure all subdirs has correct permission. not only `plugin` itself

Comment: Verified that one too, esearch user is the owner of all the files/directories under the ES base folder. Is there a way to debug this issue? all I am doing now is hit the URL and seeing 'page not available' in the browser. As there no logs at ES level, just wondering how to resolve this.